# Enable any outline mode for markdown

Tags: customize, markdown-mode, outline

First of all, from http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AllOut:

> Allout outline mode is part of GnuEmacs.
>
> Allout outline mode provides extensive outline formatting and
>   manipulation beyond standard emacs outline mode. It provides for
>   structured editing of outlines, as well as navigation and exposure. It
>   also provides for syntax-sensitive text like programming languages.
>   (For an example, see the allout code itself, which is organized in an
>   allout outline framework.)

If you view the “allout.el” itself, and trigger `M-x allout-hide-bodies`, you’ll get an indented outline view of the source code.

How can I configure `allout-mode` to understand markdown syntax so that I can use it to navigate and show/hide sections in a markdown file?

Thanks

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. For one thing, markdown is mentioned in the title but nowhere in the question. For another, what do you mean by "*can somehow get configured*"?

Comment: It sounds like the question is: how does one configure allout mode to treat markdown headers as outline elements. @xpt, is that correct? I've personally never used allout, though.

Comment: Yep, @glucas, exactly. The `allout` mode is really nice, if you follow the above wiki, view the “allout.el” itself, and trigger `M-x allout-hide-bodies`, you’ll love it right there.

Comment: OK, I edited the bit at the end to hopefully clarify the question. Feel free to further correct it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand the question, you are looking for a way to edit markdown files where you can show or hide sections, navigate by headings and so on.

I've never used `allout-mode` but it does look like you could configure it to recognize markdown syntax. However, another option is to take a look at [markdown-mode](http://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/) which supports navigation and folding, e.g.

> markdown-mode supports outline-minor-mode as well as org-mode-style visibility cycling for atx- or hash-style headings. There are two types of visibility cycling: Pressing S-TAB cycles globally between the table of contents view (headings only), outline view (top-level headings only), and the full document view. Pressing TAB while the point is at a heading will cycle through levels of visibility for the subtree: completely folded, visible children, and fully visible.

Comment: Oh, that works great. Thanks. I've edited the title to reflect the correct answer. Feel free to tweak it further.